# Tutorial for summation recursion in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to write a program that carries out a up and then a down recursion for a function and I am totally lost as to how to start. I have looked at the python documentation and found it more confusing than helpful. I would appreciate it if anyone can point me in the right direction regarding tutorials, and or documentation on the conventions for summation in python. thanks

Comment: is this homework? what have you tried so far?

Comment: I really have no idea what you are trying to do? Is it to understand recursion? Recursively sum a sequence? What do you mean by "up" and "down" recursion?

Comment: I am trying to write code that will solve the up and down recursion relations for the spherical Bessel function

Comment: I would strongly recommend not trying to implement spherical Bessel functions yourself, scipy ships with solid well tested versions of these functions: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/special.html#spherical-bessel-functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing recursive function can be tricky to get your head around, but there are good references for getting better at solving such problems. I would strongly recommend getting a copy of ["A little schemer"](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/BTLS/). Working in a language like scheme may be easier than coming straight to this in python.

In python, a recursive summation can be written as:

```
def rsum( seq ):
    if not seq:
        return 0
    else:
        return seq[0] + rsum(seq[1:])
```

Working from first principles, it is worth noting that this function follows a very common pattern, it is an example of a [fold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29). In python you can write `foldl` and `foldr` as:

```
def foldl( f, z, xs ):
    if not xs:
        return z
    else:
        return foldl(f, f(z, xs[0]), xs[1:])

def foldr( f, z, xs ):
    if not xs:
        return z
    else:
        return f(xs[0], foldr(f, z, xs[1:]))
```

Using a higher order building block this means you can really write `rsum` as:

```
def rsum(seq):
    return foldl( lambda a,b: a+b, 0, seq )
```

Or:

```
def rsum(seq):
    return foldr( lambda a,b: a+b, 0, seq )
```

Comment: You can always use the built in sum. http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sum

Comment: Of course you can use the built in sum function, but that isn't what the question was.

Comment: Possibly relevant: I think foldl is equivalent to `functools.reduce`, although that probably isn't implemented recursively.

Comment: @Andrew Walker. Thank you for the reply. How would one use a formula say (x^2+1) from x=0 to 10 for example in your example?

Comment: In the general case? I wouldn't use recursion. I'd simply use the builtin `sum` and a generator expression: `sum( ( x**2 + 1 for x in xrange(10) ) )`. It wouldn't be wrong to use `rsum` as defined in the answer, but it would be significantly slower.

Comment: @Andrew Walker its really that easy Wow!! Thank you!

Comment: Hi I tried to write a small practice code   ``sum =      sum(((n+1)/(x+1)) for n in range(2) for x in range(2))
sum+= sum
print(sum)``, but it gives a value of 9 not 3 as extected

Answer (score 1):

Here is the official slides for Problem Solving with Algorithms and Data Structures:

http://www.pythonworks.org/pythonds/Slides.zip?attredirects=0&d=1

You can check Chapter 3, it's about recursion algorithm.

Comment: Thanks Tao I will check it out!